# How to change the Title of the window in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, window, title

How to change the title of the window in Qt? (Both for `QDialog` and `QMainWindow`.)

Answer (score 151, accepted):

```
void    QWidget::setWindowTitle ( const QString & )
```

EDIT: **If you are using QtDesigner**, on the property tab, there is an editable property called ***windowTitle*** which can be found under the QWidget section. The property tab can usually be found on the lower right part of the designer window.

Comment: Just for completeness here is it explained: qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#windowTitle-prop

Comment: I dont know about other people, but stackoverflow is becoming a very useful documentation alternative, google often points me here before the actual documentation (and its also easier to read).

Comment: @chacham15 The Qt documentation is quite good and very easy to read.  SO doesn't even come close for simple what-is-the-function-name questions; we do better at slightly more complicated problems.

Comment: Maybe good to know: better put the "setWindowTitle()" at the end of the constructor

Comment: Is there a way to change font-family of the window title? Also can we make it appear bold?

Answer (score 63):

For new Qt users this is a little more confusing than it seems if you are using QT Designer and `.ui` files.

Initially I tried to use `ui->setWindowTitle`, but that doesn't exist.  `ui` is not a `QDialog` or a `QMainWindow`.

The owner of the `ui` is the `QDialog` or `QMainWindow`, the `.ui` just describes how to lay it out. In that case, you would use:

```
this->setWindowTitle("New Title");
```

I hope this helps someone else.

Comment: @UmNyobe The code generated from that .ui file will call `Owner->setWindowTitle()`, so it's no different.  If you want the window title to be dynamic, you'd do it this way rather than in the .ui file.

Comment: +1 for giving an example of actually implementing this in the code.

Comment: Note that this method is not `protected` and can be called from outside the dialog class as well.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is years later but I ran into the same problem. The solution I found was to change the window title in main.cpp. I guess once the `w.show();` is called the window title can no longer be changed. In my case I just wanted the title to reflect the current directory and it works.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
w.setWindowTitle(QDir::currentPath());
w.show();

return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also modify the **windowTitle** attribute in Qt Designer.

Answer (score -4):

```
system("title WhateverYouWantToNameIt");
```

Comment: You should put a brief description of your answer.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Does this work? Is this even Qt? I never heard of this function.