# How to change the title of QtWidgets.QApplication

Tags: python

I am making an app with the code from [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42820364/displaying-websites-with-python) Stackoverflow page:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtGui,QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w=QWebEngineView()
w.load(QtCore.QUrl('https://google.com')) ## load google on startup
w.showMaximized()
app.exec_()
```

However,the result look like this

[Click to see](https://postimg.cc/Y4fBXHnz)

Where there is a title "pythonw"

However,I want to change it to "My App",how can I?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598269/how-to-change-the-title-of-the-window-in-qt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use "setWindowTitle":

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets,QtGui,QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *

app=QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
w=QWebEngineView()
w.load(QtCore.QUrl('https://google.com')) ## load google on startup
w.setWindowTitle("pythonw")
w.showMaximized()
app.exec_()
```

PD: This question is answered [here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10598269/how-to-change-the-title-of-the-window-in-qt) but is not in python, that is why I took my time to reply and not to flag this post.